# Cannot get two-column figures to show after the end of text

Tags: floats, two-column

I cannot force LaTeX to display my two-column figures in the end of the document.

Here's my minimal example:

```
\documentclass[nocrop]{bioinfo}

\copyrightyear{2017} \pubyear{2017}

\access{}
\appnotes{}

\begin{document}
\firstpage{1}

\title[Dummy title]{Dummy title}
\address{}
\corresp{}
\editor{}
\history{}
\abstract{}

\maketitle

\section{Introduction}

\begin{figure}[t!]
  \rule{\columnwidth}{100pt}
  \caption{Some single-column figure}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure*}[t!]
  \rule{\textwidth}{200pt}
  \caption{Some two-column figure}
\end{figure*}

\end{document}
```

(I have to use this Bioinformatics template from here: https://academic.oup.com/bioinformatics/pages/submission_online)

If I add more figures with `\begin{figure}` they will show in the end of the document on separate pages. However the second figure here does not appear anywhere, and if I add more, they also won't appear.
Is there a way to make `figure*` work like `figure` in this respect?

Comment: Do you WANT them at the end of the document?  Usually that (or the next \clearpage) is where they wind up if they won't fit anywhere else.  There is a limit on how tall a figure can be for [t].  And don't use [t!], it is like hitting the button on an elevator repeatedly to make it go faster.

Comment: @JohnKormylo Firstly, I want them to show. Then, if I have enough text, of course I would want them near the corresponding text, but if not I would want the in the end, instead of nowhere : )

Comment: BTW, you should use \columnwidth for the first figure, assuming bioinfomatics is a two column document.

Comment: even with the class file I can not reproduce the problem (the images are missing and with the default behaviour after a missing image, both figures appear in draft mode)  Please replace the `\includegraphics{...}` by `\rule{3cm}{4cm}`  or whatever size you need to make sure that the example demonstrates the problem.

Comment: It is not your fault but that zip file shows _very_ bad latex practice it distributes old versions of standard latex packages such as graphicx and color and of basic contributed packages such as float natbib etc, if you unpack the zip file make sure that these versions do not get into your tex input path.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I've updated the question code with `\rule` and I had the same problem. Then I moved my file out of the zip folder and it started working. So I guess the problem is in the old versions of packages in the zip. Thank you!

Comment: can you report that to the people distributing the class?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I sent them an email with the description of the problem and a link to this page

Comment: Removing the old .sty files as @DavidCarlisle suggests fixed a related problem for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately as well as the `bioinfo.cls` file itself the zip file distributed to authors includes obsolete versions of many packages that are part of the core latex distribution (`graphicx`, `color`) and major contributed packages including `natbib`, `float` and `stdfloats.sty` .

Some combination of these packages is breaking the current latex output routine.  If you just use `bioinfo.cls` but use current versions of all the associated packages as distributed with current tex distributions then the problem does not arise.

Most likely the problem is that the old versions of the packages are not taking account of fixes for the double float positioning that were made in the 2015 release of latex.

Comment: Maybe I'm just stupid, but, I've updated all my latex packages---how do I specify the usage of the latest versions? Do I add `\usepackage{...}` in the preamble?